# What kind of scorpion is this?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, arachnology, arthropod

This is in Nevada; it's about the size of a tooth pick in length.

[image: brown scorpion]
(click to enlarge)

What kind of scorpion is this?

Comment: Welcome Samantha. Please take our [tour] and refer to thee [help] for guidance. I've edited to make the image work, which will apply once approved. Please tell us how big the toothpicks are in your part of the world as they vary quite a bit in size over the international community which visits here.